# Stop ongoing MySQL injection

Tags: sql-injection

This is not about SQL injection prevention, which is covered in other questions. My question is: Once an attack succeeds, is there a way to completely stop the attack right away while we look for and fix the vulnerability? I'm hoping to keep the database online for regular users, but prevent damage to it.

Comment: There isn't a way to just stop injections. You could change the application's credentials and `GRANT` to prevent insert/update if that's what's being injected, but if you experience a `SELECT` injection (stealing data, elevating privs, etc) you pretty much have to take the database offline. If you are under attack, it is _highly recommended_ to take your site offline immediately.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I appreciate the advice. The site is around 18,000 pages. Is there a way of taking it offline that does not involve deleting it all and re-uploading later?

Comment: Configure the web server to deny access. If you run Apache for example, put a .htaccess in the root with `Deny from all`

Comment: You should build in a database call or file check that allows you to quickly flip your site into maintenance mode. Deny from all is good in a pinch, but without a redirect, it will be pretty ugly.

Comment: Thanks Michael and dgig. Yes, deny from all is ugly as hell, but it did what we wanted: Froze everything until we plugged the hole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the database into read-only mode, if your application can handle it - and I stress the IF. 
Still, that leaves the wide field of information-disclosure vulnerability (e.g. if you encrypted passwords instead of hashing them with a strong hash algorithm + salt, birthday dates (credit card fraud), email addresses - spammers lov'em). 
The only way to really prevent the leak from being exploited is to take the database offline **IMMEDIATELY**, fix the bugs, and then put it back online as fast as possible.

An intermediate solution would be to backup the database (after setting it read-only), and then update all confidential information with bogus information on the online version.

e.g.

```
UPDATE T_Users SET e_mail = 'undisclosed@undisclosed.com', birthdate = '19000101'
```

Comment: Thanks Quandary. We found and fixed the vulnerability. Passwords were hash + salt. Fortunately no credit card info in the database. The attacker changed much of the database to gibberish so we will revert to the last backup (3 days ago). Anyone reading this: How old is your last backup?

Comment: Taking the website offline is the **only** reasonable reaction.

Comment: @blogo: My last backup is from yesterday evening 19:00 o'clock CEST. Transferred from db disk to tape drive, and via internet onto another server at a different location (fire-safety).

Comment: @blogo: Hope that account did not have sysadmin privileges, otherwise it would be wiser to reinstall the database server. --- Compromised is compromised, no compromise --- .